# How to make a sub connection to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this config file.

```
<?PHP
$s_ipserver1 = "10.0.0.101";
$db_porta1    = "3306";
$db_user1     = "user";
$db_password1 = "123456";
$db_name1     = "name";

$s_ipserver2 = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$db_porta2    = "3306";
$db_user2     = "user";
$db_password2 = "123456";
$db_name2     = "name";

$s_ipserver3 = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$db_porta3    = "3306";
$db_user3     = "user";
$db_password3 = "123456";
$db_name3     = "name";
?>
```

And I want to convert it to something like this.

```
<?PHP

$dbL = "1";// Que servidor é este? 1, 2 ou 3.

$s_ipserver1 = "10.0.0.101";
$db_porta1    = "3306";
$db_user1     = "user";
$db_password1 = "123456";
$db_name1     = "name";

$s_ipserver2 = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$db_porta2    = "3306";
$db_user2     = "user";
$db_password2 = "123456";
$db_name2     = "name";

$s_ipserver3 = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$db_porta3    = "3306";
$db_user3     = "user";
$db_password3 = "123456";
$db_name3     = "name";

$s_ipserver  = "$s_ipserver$dbL";
$db_porta    = "$db_porta$dbL";
$db_user     = "$db_user$dbL";
$db_password = "$db_password$dbL";
$db_name     = "$db_name$dbL";
?>
```

This is one of the connection files.

```
<?PHP
include_once("/pasta/config.php");
$db_host1     = "$s_ipserver1:$db_porta1";
$db_link1     = mysql_connect($db_host1, $db_user1, $db_password1) or die (mysql_error ());
$db_connect1  = mysql_select_db($db_name1, $db_link1);
```

?>

And I need to get something like this.

```
<?PHP
include_once("/pasta/config.php");
$db_host      = "$s_ipserver:$db_porta";
$db_link      = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password) or die (mysql_error ());
$db_connect   = mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_link);
?>
```

Where is my mistake.
All original files are working perfectly.

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: Why are you defining so many variables instead of a single one, like an array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @tadman, but my system still works with MYSQL and I will make every effort to keep this up

Comment: PDO is just another, better way to access MySQL. It doesn't require switching databases. Don't think `mysql_query` is the de-facto way of doing this because it hasn't been since the 1990s.

Comment: You should so bare in mind that the mysql interface is deprecated, check the php manual for confirmation, failure to upgrade may make futureproofing yihr system hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not as clean and beautiful code but solves my problem the server need to bind himself by choosing from 3 possible connections with small variable `$dbL`

In /pasta/config.php

```
<?PHP

$dbL = "1";// Que servidor é este? 1, 2 ou 3.

$s_ipserver1 = "10.0.0.101";
$db_porta1    = "3306";
$db_user1     = "user";
$db_password1 = "123456";
$db_name1     = "name";

$s_ipserver2 = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$db_porta2    = "3306";
$db_user2     = "user";
$db_password2 = "123456";
$db_name2     = "name";

$s_ipserver3 = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$db_porta3    = "3306";
$db_user3     = "user";
$db_password3 = "123456";
$db_name3     = "name";
?>
```

In /pasta/subconnect.php

```
<?php 
include_once("/pasta/config.php");
$ipserver  = 's_ipserver'. $dbL;
$porta     = 'db_porta'. $dbL;
$user      = 'db_user'. $dbL;
$password  = 'db_password'. $dbL;
$name      = 'db_name'. $dbL;
?>
```

In /pasta/connect.php

```
<?PHP
include_once("/pasta/subconnect.php");
$host      = $$ipserver . ':'. $$porta;
$link      = mysql_connect($host, $$user, $$password) or die (mysql_error ());
$db_connect   = mysql_select_db($$name, $link);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use an array syntax for your connexion variables ?

```
$connexion[1]=['server'=>'10.0.0.101','port'=>'3306','user'=>'user','password'=>'123456','dbname'=>'name'];
```

or

```
$s_ipserver[1] = "10.0.0.101";
$db_porta[1]    = "3306";
$db_user[1]     = "user";
$db_password[1] = "123456";
$db_name[1]     = "name";
```

Comment: First style has syntax error! `$array = array('key'=> 'val');`

Comment: @undone ['k'=>'v'] array syntax is supported from php5.4 and above. php5.3 is obsolete

Comment: My problem is not in connection with 3 servers but need to change the number at $dbL and he takes the number I put there

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create another connection you need to set 4th param to true, otherwise it would resuse existing connection, causing the last selected DB to be the one used in both connections:

```
$db_link      = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, TRUE) or die (mysql_error ());
$db_connect   = mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_link);
```

More on the 4th param:

```
If a second call is made to mysql_connect() with the same arguments, no new link will be established, but instead, the link identifier of the already opened link will be returned. The new_link parameter modifies this behavior and makes mysql_connect() always open a new link, even if mysql_connect() was called before with the same parameters. In SQL safe mode, this parameter is ignored.
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php